# WPF DataGrid CurrenItem at the top

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, currentitem

I implemented a DataGrid via WPF MVVM where I'd like to "scroll" to a particular item. I don't want to select the correspond row though. Using the CurrenItem property works fine, but it "scrolls" to the target row at the bottom of the data grid (or more precisely to the full row at the bottom - there can be also be a partially displayed row below the target row).

Below an **over-simplified** version of what I implemented :

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items;

    public ItemModel CurrentItem { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();

        ..

        CurrentItem = Items[..];
    }
}
```

```
<DataGrid
    CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      
    <!-- .. -->
    
</DataGrid>
```

PS I don't want to use external framework.

Thanks for any insights.